# AngularJS UI-Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using AngularJS and [AngularUI Bootstrap's Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).
I want to use the filter with multiple parameters.
Here is my input control:

```
<input id="tbUsers" class="form-control" ng-model="unit.userSel"
                                typeahead="user as user._FName + '(' +  user._LName +')' for user in allUsers | filter:{_FName : _LName:$viewValue}:myFunc | limitTo:8"                                    
                                typeahead-editable="false" required />
```

In my controller I have function for myFunc:

```
$scope.myFunc = function (FName, LName, viewValue) {
    //logic here
    return true;
}
```

I am unable to pass multiple parameters to myFunc. If I remove the LName param from controller function and the input filter, then it works fine. If I add 2 parameters, myFunc doesn't get called.

Please help!! 
P.S.: My first question here, so I might have broken a few rules, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are many solutions to the problem you face. If you want the "proper answer", the filter is done through Angular's filter module so you should take a look at the following: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter (one easy way to do it would just be to combine two parameters in an ng-model)

If you want a really easy answer... You could just pass it the object instead of a property of an object, that way it filters on everything.

Comment: Well true about that, but then I need to filter only on 2 fields, and that object is huge, with more than 10 fields. Angular's filter module looks like a feasible way for now.

Comment: The filter in UI bootstrap is based off filter (so you can essentially do the same stuff...)